# Where do I put the constructor call for my new view engine?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razorengine

I created my own RazorViewEngine and I am putting the following in the startup.configureservices call.

```
        services.AddSingleton<IRazorViewEngine, RoleBasedRazorViewEngine>();
        services.AddMvc();
```

My new viewengine is being called as expected but I want to add values to the constructor for some "RoleBase" view control.  The logic finds a view based on the role provided or if not found goes to the default view.

Where is the constructor called so that I can provide it with a list of roles for it to use in the look up.

An alternative method is also acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer through other searches and figured it out.  The Startup.cs functions similar to a unity dependency injection where it puts the default versions of the interface.  For example if you have an interface IDataManager which by default you want to use MyDataManager as the class that implements the interface you could do the following:

```
services.AddTransient<IDataManager, MyDataManager>();
```

Simple just like the unity used to do it.  Sometimes I need it to be more explicitly stated. I am still researching the other services.Add***** methods but transient seems to be the catchall for things not specifically spelled out with the other services.Add methods.